# Use of multiple grid containers

Tags: css, grid, responsive-design

I am using the 960gs method and i would like to use a totally different grid if the size of the browser turns on the breaking point,  how do i make this possible?

Example:

```
<div class="container_22"> # 1920 design
    <div class="grid_22">
        - header -
    </div>
    <div class="grid_11">
        - content -
    </div>
    <div clas="grid_11">
        - content -
    </div>
</div>
```

Browser width for example turns on breakingpoint

```
<div class="container_8"> # 1280 design
    <div class="grid_8">
        - header -
    </div>
    <div class="grid_4">
        - content -
    </div>
    <div clas="grid_4">
        - content -
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Media queries? They might help you set a specific class at a different size http://www.scripttheweb.com/design/css-media-queries-beginners-guide/